# ubuntu support to backup plus 1TB external hard drive

Tags: 12.04

I have installed ubuntu 12.04 on my desktop .as my internal storage is very less (80gb) ,I am planning to by Seagate Backup Plus 1 TB External Hard Disk for use .
Will ubuntu will support to this exterbal drive to use ? 
Is there anything i need to do affter connecting to my desktop ?

My system specs are :processor :intel core 2 duo , 1.5 gb ram DDR2 ,Ubuntu 12.04 OS.

Thanks ,Satish

Answer (score 0):

Shortly, yes.

On the other side, it depends what file system you're using. If, by default, you instaleld your ubuntu with ext4 file system, then it supports up to [1 EiB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) and it should be alright.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems fine and it will support it easily.

Ubuntu is a plug and play so as soon as you will plug your External it will be detected automatically and will be mounted(by default) in `/media` directory.